# How to find the top X reoccruing values in a table or range that are not numeric?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Consider the following table:
A1:B6 is defined as a table, Table1

```
  +----+-----------+
  | A  | B         |
  +----+-----------+
1 | ID | Title     |
  +----+-----------+
2 | 01 | Error 404 |
  +----+-----------+
3 | 02 | Error 404 |
  +----+-----------+
4 | 03 | Error 404 |
  +----+-----------+
5 | 05 | Error 500 |
  +----+-----------+
6 | 06 | Error 500 |
  +----+-----------+
7 | 07 | Error 600 |
  +----+-----------+
```

If I want to find the most common entry with a formula from 'Table1[Title]' I would get the result "Error 404". I have achieved this like so:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Title],MODE(MATCH(Table1[Title],Tabel1[Title],0)))
```

If I was looking for the top 3 I would get:

```
    +-----------+
    | D         |
    +-----------+
  1 | Error 404 |
    +-----------+
  2 | Error 500 |
    +-----------+
  3 | Error 600 |
    +-----------+
```

I haven't found an easy/scalable way to do this with anything more than the top 1.

Comment: what about a pivot table? add "title" both as row title and "value" summarized by count. Then you can sort the pivot table descending by the values (2nd) column.

Comment: What kind of table is this  (Excel, SQL database, flat file, etc.)?  If it's not already in a SQL database, can you import it into one?  From there, writing a query would be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming excel or google sheets) Can you add a couple of extra columns that count instances and calculate a RANK for instances?

See example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1koKYjrvdvahsA_DhxBnymlIQToH339GPSr0OHXA_PsI/edit?usp=sharing

Note: Adding row/1000000 to the count prevents duplicate counts and therefore forces the rank function to output unique ranks even for duplicate counts, sorted in inverse order of appearance. ;)